# Select row with radio and update table

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I have a table with select row with radio button and when click button, the status updated in mysql table but when I click the button, the last user updated and other user not.

```
 <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="frmUser" >
 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php
      $qr=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user`");
       while($row=$qr->fetch_object()){
    ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
     </input></td>
    <td class="blck min"><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
    <td><span>
     <input type="submit" value="" id="st" name="st">
     <?php
          if(isset($_POST['st'])){
           $rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
            for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
            if($row->status == 'ENABLE'){
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE `user` SET `status`='DISABLE' WHERE `id`='" . $_POST["users"][$i] . "'");
            }
            else{
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE `user` SET `status`='ENABLE' WHERE `id`='" . $_POST["users"][$i] . "'");
            }
            }
            header("location:users.php");
            }
         ?>
     </span></td>
   </tr>
   <?php}?>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: any error?? or what you getting??

Comment: What do you actually mean?

Comment: i want update status user in mysql when select row and click the submit button but it is work only last user!not all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please place below line and check how much count is display:

```
$rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
print('<pre>COUNT :: ' . $rowCount . ' >> ');
print_r($_POST["users"]);
print('</pre>');exit;
```

Above code just display your count value only.

Let me know for more help.!

Comment: status

COUNT :: 1 >> Array
(
    [0] => 20
)

Comment: And what is the output if you put below code:

`for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
    print ""status > "" . $i . "" :: "" . $row->status . '/n';
    if($row->status == 'ENABLE'){
            $mysqli->query(""UPDATE `user` SET `status`='DISABLE' WHERE `id`='"" . $_POST[""users""][$i] . ""'"");
    }
    else{
        $mysqli->query(""UPDATE `user` SET `status`='ENABLE' WHERE `id`='"" . $_POST[""users""][$i] . ""'"");
    }
}`

Above code will tell you that which records having which status. Match there status with already exist data which you want to update.

Comment: So finally issue is here that i=0 for all 20 records, which is wrong and need to correct out it.